# URL Matcher in spring boot with regular expression

Tags: regex, spring-boot, spring-mvc, get-mapping

I have requirement to handle all request except few with single handler method in spring boot.

The valid urls that should be serveed -

```
/test/login
/test/dashboard
/test/validate/details
```

and the invalid urls that should not be served is -

```
/test/asset/login
/test/asset
/test/validate/asset
```

basically any URL which contains string "asset" should not be handled.

So far I am trying it as follows but it's not working -

```
@GetMapping("test/{path:^(?!.*(asset))}")
    String hello(String path){
        return "hello>>" + path;
    }
```

But this is not working.  I think there is some problem with the regex that I am using.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do ? to accept only 3 routes defined above? , for URLs that contain asset word it can be handled with 404 routing

Comment: can you try this regex ^(?!.*(asset))\/test\/\w+\/?\w+

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/6QxHwx/1

Comment: @MuhammadNuman Used this in getmapping but it's not working.. throwing 404 for any url I enter

Comment: sorry I did not use getmapping before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(?:(?!asset).)*$
```

Comment: Getting error - 
The number of capturing groups in the pattern segment (^((?!asset).)*$) does not match the number of URI template variables it defines, which can occur if capturing groups are used in a URI template regex. Use non-capturing groups instead.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The number of capturing groups in the pattern segment (^((?!asset).)*$) does not match the number of URI template variables it defines, which can occur if capturing groups are used in a URI template regex. Use non-capturing groups instead.

Comment: Fixed to non-capturing group: ^(?:(?!asset).)*$